# Android layout not showing; background changed

Tags: android-layout

I was trying to build my project based on an existed projects. However I found whatever I build in a layout xml it never shows anything on screen.

even the simplest layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">         
<TextView android:id="@+id/status_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:text="@string/msg_default_status"
android:textColor="@color/status_text"
android:textSize="14sp"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:onClick="aaaaa" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and corresponding java file

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);  
}
public void aaaaa(View view)
{
//empty
}
```

The layout shows OK on the graphical layout in eclipse with button and textview on right position and with a black background, as the overall background; but when I run it on the emulator this page only shows a white, not black screen, and nothing on that except the title; What's more, if I try to load the original main layout, i.e,

```
setContentView(R.layout.OriginalMainLayout);
```

(I've already changed android.intent.action.main to right place in manifest)It still gave me a white screen. How can I solve it?

Comment: Try remove the line `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"` from your simplest layout.

Comment: @Neoh I tried to remove this but nothing happened.